# pushwoosh push notification for ionic does not work with android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, pushwoosh

I cant get Android Push to work with ionic. (ios works by the way)

I followed the documentation here:

http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap

I even tried to create the same sample app based on this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-P2O1jmb7fI

And it does not work on Android (ios works though).

I configured PushWoosh and the app something like below:

```
Application code: XXXXX-XXXXX (formatted hex appcode id)
google server key: 123456789012345678901234567890123456789 (39 hex key)
google project number: 123456789012 (mine has 12 digits)
GCM API is enabled
```

I can see in the PushWoosh there is Android device registered, but why
cant I receive the push ? Is there something i need to do on phone,
code, etc ? I even try to put breakpoint into addEventListener but nothing received.

Really need Android to work with Push Notification. Thanks!

I am using device:

```
Redmi Note 2
Android version 5.0.2 LRX22G
```

Didnt also work with emulator:

```
Android 5.0.2
Build number: sdk_google_phone_x86-eng 5.0.2 LSY66D 1797986test-keys
```

PushWoosh response (will update when I'ved recreate new keys for these):

```
As far as I can see in your Push History, there are some "Unauthorized" errors. There are three possible scenarios why you are getting the "Unauthorized" error:

The Google Project number in your application isn't the one in Google Console;
The API key in your Control Panel isn't the same that you got in Google Console;
The API key, for some reason, doesn't work properly.
Could you please check whether your Google Project number and API key are fine?

Also, could you please try using the Browser Key instead of the Server Key and vice versa?
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct answer for these kind of errors. Please make sure you Google Project Id is the one that matches the Server Key. Also make sure you did not set any restrictions or white-listening on the Server Key.

Check this article on how to find Google Project Id:
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158840?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i didn not enable GCM in the correct project. Was always assuming the primary project api enabled works for all.